# Is it possible to build application using Javascript on Linux platforms?

Tags: javascript

Javascript is widely used to create apps in the web. How about desktop, etc? Gnome Shell is made of it. I'm just curious if there's a way or something which allows devs to access Gnome/Clutter graphics libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three best options that I know of are [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (using Swing, or other Java graphics frameworks), [Seed](http://live.gnome.org/Seed), and [Gjs](http://live.gnome.org/Gjs/).

Seed and Gjs are both Gnome projects that bind the GTK+ and Gnome libraries to JavaScript. Seed uses the JavaScriptCore runtime from WebKit and Gjs uses Mozilla's Spidermonkey engine. Gnome Shell is using Gjs.

Another option that, as far as I know, is still pretty immature is [Gom](http://code.google.com/p/ilovegom/). Instead of just a JavaScript binding for GTK+, it has an HTML-like DOM interface.

Comment: I also want to point out that both Seed and GJS support Clutter through GObjectIntrospection.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. Besides Rhino, V8/node.js is one of them.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Node.js, it's a great and fun way to build servers

Comment: But it's not really Gnome related. Yet you still get my +1 for mentioning Rhino although it's not as fun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using Rhino although it looks like a convolated path...

Answer (score 0):

Check this [recent post](http://www.akbkhome.com/blog.php/View/185/Javascript_on_the_Desktop_well_Linux_Mostly.html) by Alan Knowles.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about the Gnome/Clutter graphics access, But several SSJS ([Server-side_JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript)) available that can work on Linux environments.